# How to call another Java file in ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am creating a graphical interface for my program. When I press the start button, I want it to call another program.

Below is my listerner code:

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==startButton)
            ?????
    }
}
```

What should I do? I intend to call another Java file (Start.java).

Comment: 1) Stop thinking of them as 'Java files'.  They are classes. 2) You'd do it exactly the same way in an `actionPerformed()` as the `main()` 3) Figure out such simple things at an early stage, ***long*** before attempting GUI programming.

Comment: You want to start to think about it not in terms of "another Java file", but rather that you want to *execute a method on another object*.  The file is an artifact of people writing software - but mentally, you want to adopt a model of objects and methods.

Comment: this question is already answered..

go through this [link][1].



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346978/java-using-an-actionlistener-to-call-a-function-in-another-class-on-an-object-f

Comment: ok. thanks for the answer and the advice .. i will notice about that . thanks for u all again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a new Start instance there, you could do that:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==startButton) {
       Start myStart = new Start();
       myStart.foo();
    }
}
```

Or if you already have a reference to an existing Start object, then simply call its methods. A caveat, if any of Start's methods take a long time to complete or are resource hogs, you'll want to do them in a background thread such as supplied by a SwingWorker object.

Note that my answer is quite general and perhaps a bit vague on the details, but I cannot supply any finer grained details until you tell us a lot more about the structure of your program,  your classes, and your specific problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the required method of Start class if this belongs to your project and is already included in class path.

If you want to launch another process alltogether you have to use 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)