# Using actionperform to call a method in others class for Java

Tags: java, action

I'm programming a download button, when the user clicks the download button, it will call the method(`getDownload()`) in others class which is not inside a same Java program for execution and pass back the message when the process is finish but I get some error display in my client side program.

Now, btn2 is my download button, I tried to use the class to create an object to invoke the method inside it but it fails to work:

```
 if(e.getSource()== btn2)
       {
             String choice3 = String.valueOf(cmb3.getSelectedIndex());
             runCC(choice3);
       }
 public static void runCC(String choice3)
       {
         DownloadCenter dc = new DownloadCenter();
         String ServerReplyMessage = dc.getDownload(choice3);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Downloading" +ServerReplyMessage);
       }
```

I get an error in

```
DownloadCenter dc = new DownloadCenter()
```

and the error message is

> constructor DownloadCenter in class DownloadCenter can't apply to given type

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346978/java-using-an-actionlistener-to-call-a-function-in-another-class-on-an-object-f) is the link that is reference idea for me to develop the program but why it still gives error? Can I know where is my error?

[This](http://codepad.org/12e0rU8j) is my full program for the other class.

Answer (score 0):

The `constructor` you have specified in the `class DownloadCenter` requires a `String` parameter to make an `object`...
While you are making an `object` without passing the `string` parameter...

Now you can do two things...

1. Provide a `default constructor` in the `class DownloadCenter`.

```
public DownloadCenter()
{
  // do what you want...
}
```

**or**

2. Make the `object` by passing a `String` Parameter.

```
DownloadCenter dc = new DownloadCenter("Your_String_Value");
```

For more on constructors in java [see this](http://www.javatpoint.com/constructor)

Comment: it solve my problem but why there didn't have any response when I click the download button ?

Comment: show your full code so that your problem can be solved